# Client uses a cached bot version post deployment

Tags: node.js, botframework

Client browser session, on the web channel, displays deprecated dialogs and functionality in recently deployed version. The issue is resolved once cache is purged, am I missing a step or setting in deployment?

I'm using nodeJS SDK4.4 using Kudu for Azure deployment.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using Azure DevOps for deployment instead of a .zip deploy or right click > publish. There is a guide on how to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript?view=azure-devops), then you can take advantage of the "Remove Existing Files at Destination" option that is part of the "App Service Deploy" step as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341194/5209435). If you don't like the YAML syntax you can use the GUI as per [this guide](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/devops/1486/azure-devops-build-deploy-nodejs).

Comment: Thank you Matt. I've switched to a bitbucket pipeline, not seen a 'Remove Existing Files at Destination' option but will try adding to the YAML. Note that my issue is with 2 clients browser sessions showing different functionality. I'm not sure this is necessarily the solution?

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that the issue was with 2 browser sessions, interesting... You should definitely update your original question to include this piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Kudu specifically to deploy to the bot framework; the MSBF supports using the [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg) to deploy (though this seems to be similar enough, in that it is a "zip deployment"). That being said, it's possible the Kudu deployment method is somehow being delayed.

One option you could try is to enable continuous deployment through Github. It's as simple as authorizing Azure to look at the github repo you have your bot code in. [image: Select 'Deployment Center' then on the right blade, select 'GitHub']

The Bot Framework has a how-to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: thanks JJ. I did have CI connected to my bitbucket repo, but this mysteriously started throwing an authentication error after a merge - any ideas why that would be? I've now reverted to using a pipeline from bitbucket - so far so good, but thinking maybe I should migrate to Github or DevOps?